# How to access name of a list in a list of lists

Tags: python, excel, list, pandas

I have a scenario where I have a list of lists:

```
list1 = [aa] + [bb] + [cc]
list2 = [dd] + [ee] + [ff]
...
listn

listoflists = []
listoflists.append((list1, list2, ..., listn))
```

I need to iterate through the list of lists by making a dataframe that pulls each list and creates an excel file of each list and saves it with the file name: `list1.xlsx`, `list2.xlsx`, etc. In order to do this, however, I need to be able extract the names of lists from the list of lists.

Maybe I am approaching this problem in completely the wrong way. But if anyone could offer some advice, it would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: `listoflists.append((list1, list2, ..., listn))` puts a tuple of lists into your list. So do you have a list of lists or do you have a list of a tuple of lists?

Comment: this part is worring: "I need to be able extract the names of lists"... you need an ordered dict for that specific part, but what is the source of the problem you are trying to solve?  what are `aa` and alike? or it is just an excercise for creating `pandas` dataframe?

Comment: Why not use a list of lists from the start? Or use a dict to keep track of your lists, then you can iterate it to build your list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some changes for test in lists, don't care about this ;)

Try this:

```
l1 = ['a','b'] + ['c','d']+['e','f']
l2 = ['g','h']+['i','j']+['k','l']

listOfLists = []

listOfLists.append((l1, l2))

for lis in listOfLists[0]:
    name = [k for k,v in locals().items() if v is lis][0]
    # here is rest of your code to create excel file
```

Answer (score 0):

## You need to use list of dictionaries

```
list1 = {"name": "list1", "data": [aa] + [bb] + [cc]}
list2 = {"name": "list2", "data": [dd] + [ee] + [ff]}
listN = {"name": "listN", "data": [xx] + [yy] + [zz]}

listoflists = []
listoflists.append((list1, list2, ..., listN))

for list in listoflists:
    file = open(list["name"], "w+")
    file.write(list["data"])
    file.close()
```